# Camera control with Camera API with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to enable and disable the camera with the help of a switch in my UI using Camera API. I am following the guidelines from https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect to start and stop preview. However I get **unresolved reference error** for startPreview(), stopPreview() and release() methods. Any help would be appreciated. My disable camera method is as follows:

```
// camera disable
fun disableCamera() = {
    // stop the preview and free the camera
    stopPreviewAndFreeCamera()
    cameraExecutor.shutdown()
}

private fun stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {
    camera.apply {
        try {
            // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
            stopPreview()
            setPreviewCallback(null)
            release()
            camera = null
        } catch (err: Exception) {
            Log.e("GWAPI", "camera release failed", err)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `camera`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you question. What do you mean by type?

Comment: Which class is `camera` an instance of? (the full class name including the package name).

Comment: camera is an instance of Camera class from android.hardware.camera package. I also understand that this class have been deprecated and use of android.hardware.camera2 is recommended. But my question is can I still use the Camera class and public methods of this class such as startPreview(), stopPreview(), and release()?

Comment: Does Kotlin's `apply {}` work with method calls, or only assignment to member variables?

Comment: I have tried this way and also without    apply {} In both the cases, the public methods of class Camera are not accessible.